# Accessing GCP Secret Version Value using Discovery.build with python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

Weird instance happening when trying to pull a secret version value using python. I created a client with the discovery.build method, here: https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/secretmanager_v1.projects.secrets.versions.html

```
sm = discovery.build("secretmanager", "v1", credentials = credentials)
```

I can return the secret,

```
response = self.sm.projects().secrets().versions().access(name 'projects/17344xxxxx/secrets/api/versions/latest').execute()
pwd = response['payload']['data']
```

I am not sure how to decode the response to get the actual value, for after filtering the dictionary down, it returns a string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decode the [base64 encoded string data](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/rest/v1/SecretPayload) to utf-8

```py
import base64
pwd = base64.b64decode(response['payload']['data']).decode("utf-8")
```